# how to execute PHP script on incoming mail?

Tags: linux, centos6, exim, dovecot

My centos server has Exim 4.87 and Dovecot 2.2 running.

How can I make a PHP script execute when a new mail for a particular email address myuser@mydomain.com is received?
I read somewhere that Dovecot´s notify plugin can be of help, but there is no documentation on how to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I set a script to execute when new mail is recieved for a particular email address:

**exim.conf under MAIN CONFIGURATION SETTINGS:**

```
system_filter = /etc/exim/system_filter.conf
```

**/etc/exim/system_filter.conf:**

```
if $h_to: contains "myuser@myhost.com"
then
   unseen pipe "/usr/local/bin/my_filter.php $message_size"
endif
```

Comment: No matter where I put the `system_filter = /etc/exim/system_filter.conf
` line, Exim rewrites the exim.conf file after I restart it. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Jim U's suggestion was a good starting point. However, after some research on system filters, I found out that cPanel actually provides a mail forwarding and script piping mechanism which is exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

If it is cpanel, you could add following entry in  /etc/valiases/mydomain.com file

**myuser@mydomain.com | /usr/bin/php -q /some/path/pipe.php**